# Zipping specific elements of a list in Python

Tags: python, list, python-imaging-library

I have a list that looks like this:

```
[[(0, 0), (0, 500), (0, 1000)],
[(500, 0), (500, 500), (500, 1000)],
[(1000, 0), (1000, 500), (1000, 1000)]]
```

and I need it to look like this:

```
[[(0, 0), (500, 500)],
[(0, 500), (500, 1000)],
[(500, 0), (1000, 500)],
[(500, 500), (1000, 1000)]]
```

Notice that the last element of the first list is ignored, as is the first element of the last list.

These are coordinates for image cropping in Pillow. (0, 0) and (500, 500) are the coordinates for the top left and bottom right corners of the segment.
I've been working for hours trying to figure this out, but can't.
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define 'specific elements'? I don't see the pattern.

Comment: @AlexThornton Go diagonally from the first element in the list, then continue on. However you never start at the last element. (0,0) is diagonally across from (500,500). (0,500) is diagonal to (500,1000). Skip (0,1000) and start at (500,0) which is diagonally across from (1000,500). And finally, (500,500) is diagonal to (1000,1000). Group the diagonals and you get what the OP wants for the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dat = [[(0, 0), (0, 500), (0, 1000)],
[(500, 0), (500, 500), (500, 1000)],
[(1000, 0), (1000, 500), (1000, 1000)]]

new_dat = []
for i in range(0,len(dat)-1):
    new_dat += zip(dat[i][:len(dat)-1], dat[i+1][1:])

print new_dat
```

Prints:

```
[((0, 0), (500, 500)), ((0, 500), (500, 1000)), ((500, 0), (1000, 500)), ((500, 500), (1000, 1000))]
```

With extra indentation:

```
[((0, 0), (500, 500)),
 ((0, 500), (500, 1000)),
 ((500, 0), (1000, 500)),
 ((500, 500), (1000, 1000))]
```

Comment: Hopefully I didn't make a mistake XD

Comment: Nice, only problem is that it is not a  list of lists.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: `new_dat = [list(i) for i in new_dat]`

Comment: This is exactly it. Thanks 1000x. After reading this, I only now realize that I was super close, but gave up on the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

To create complicated iterators, I find using a generator function can simplify the problem immensely:

```
L = [[(0, 0), (0, 500), (0, 1000)],
[(500, 0), (500, 500), (500, 1000)],
[(1000, 0), (1000, 500), (1000, 1000)]]

def pair_generator(it):
  it = iter(it)
  item0 = next(it)
  for item1 in it:
    yield [item0[0],item1[1]]
    yield [item0[1],item1[2]]
    item0 = item1

result = list(pair_generator(L))

print result
```